# How to use animated material icons in vuetify

Tags: css, animation, vue.js, vuetify.js, google-material-icons

By the [`v-icon` component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/icons) of Vuetify, using mainstream [material design icons](https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline) is quite straightforward like:

```
<v-icon>home</v-icon>
```

Now, I wonder if [animated material icons](https://material.io/design/iconography/animated-icons.html#) are supported and can be used in Vuetify in a similar fashion -I mean without having to add extra lines of css code etc. if possible.

In the [examples](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/icons#examples), I have noticed the usage of `fa-spin` for Font Awesome; yet it is out of scope. I am bound to Google's material icons library.

**EDIT:** The specific kind of behavior I need is in the video examples in *transitions* section here: https://material.io/design/iconography/animated-icons.html# [See how a `play` button becomes `pause` with a smooth animation when clicked].

Comment: If you only need to add some preset animation, adding the corresponding CSS from FontAwesome (with animation descriptions) might be enough (try adding `fa-spin` or similar classes to MD Icons on that demo page). But you may need something more - `hover` animations, etc. - and that's not implemented even in FA yet.

Comment: Hmm, I would not think of using font-awesome animation with MD Icons. However, I doubt that `fa-spin` or any other font-awesome animation would help create transitions like in the page: https://material.io/design/iconography/animated-icons.html# . Going to add it to question to make it cleaner though.

Comment: But why do you mention `fa-spin` then? It's a completely different story; a simple animation applicable to any icon basically. In your case, one should make a specific animation for each icon separately, no?

Answer (score 9):

I found this page when I wanted to mimic the animation of the chevron icon when toggling the [expansion panels](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/expansion-panels/#expansion-panels) within a [v-menu](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/#usage) icon. I am not sure if this is exactly what you needed, but this is how I've done it:

```
<template>
  <v-menu offset-y v-model="menuValue">
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <v-btn v-on="on" :class="{active: menuValue}">
        <v-icon>mdi-chevron-down</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </template>
  </v-menu>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        menuValue: null
      };
    }
  };
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .v-btn.active .v-icon {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is no. The `v-icon` element currently renders icons from a webfont. Fonts cannot be animated in this way. You can apply simple fade, spin, scale, and flip animations to achieve a simple transition between two icons but the complex transitions you linked to in the [Material Guidelines](https://material.io/design/iconography/animated-icons.html#) require much more work.

My recommendation is to use inline SVG icons which are available from the [official icon set](https://material.io/tools/icons/) as well as the [community driven icon set](https://materialdesignicons.com) and animate between those using CSS animation, SMIL, or JavaScript.